# Set Effort estimates through TFS Work Item SDK

Tags: .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to create a new work item in TFS using the SDK, and I'd like to set the item's effort estimates. My code at the moment looks like this

```
    var coll = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://galaxy:8080/tfs/crisp"));

    var workItemService = coll.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    var parent = workItemService.GetWorkItem(parentWorkItemId);

    WorkItemType workItemType =parent.Project.WorkItemTypes
            .Cast<WorkItemType>()
            .First(candidateType => candidateType.Name.Equals("Task"));



    WorkItem item = workItemType.NewWorkItem();
    item.Title = work.Name;


    //Set effort estimate here

    workItemService.BatchSave(new WorkItem[]{ item });
```

But there doesn't seem to be anything on the interface for WorkItem which allows me to set an effort estimate. Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it's done by using the `[]` operator on the `WorkItem` object.

```
var coll = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://galaxy:8080/tfs/crisp"), new UICredentialsProvider());

var workItemService = coll.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

var parent = workItemService.GetWorkItem(parentWorkItemId);

WorkItemType workItemType =parent.Project.WorkItemTypes
            .Cast<WorkItemType>()
            .First(candidateType => candidateType.Name.Equals("Task"));

WorkItem item = workItemType.NewWorkItem();
item.Title = "A name";

item["Original Estimate"] = duration.TotalHours;
item["Completed Work"] = duration.TotalHours;
item["Remaining Work"] = 0.0;

int workItemId = item.Save();
```

Comment: You can also refer to the fields using their 'reference name', e.g. 'Original Estimate' = 'Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate'.

Comment: I modified the answer and added 'new UICredentialsProvider()' to the GetTeamProjectCollection() call. This will display a login prompt if the current user doesn't have access.

Comment: Also, instead of using workItemService.BatchSave() - if you're only saving one work item, you may as well use item.Save(). Be careful when using BatchSave(), as you get an array of errors back that you have to handle, otherwise a work item save will 'silently' fail.